# if else condition using classNames

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There's a package called [classNames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames). I try to use it to hide show when a user switch tab, can I pass in the expression like this instead of using a flag checking true or false?

```
<div className={classNames("tab", {(this.state.selectedTab === 2), "hide"})}>
//content
</div>
```

But above code won't work.

Comment: try this: `className={classNames("tab", {"hide": this.state.selectedTab === 2})}`

Comment: Yes, but the condition is the last thing. Is an object where the keys are the classes and the values are the condition for each class. So should be something like: `classNames("tab", {"hide": this.state.selectedTab === 2})`

Comment: that is a lot of overhead code to accomplish className={ this.state.selectedTab === 2 ? "tab hide" :  "tab" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can use it like this:

```
className={classNames("tab", {"hide": this.state.selectedTab === 2})}
```

Reason is, `key` will be the the name of `class` and in place of value you can use any **condition** which will return `true or false`, if condition will be `true` then hide will be applied otherwise it will get ignored.